# No Man's Sky: Atlas Rises - How to deconstruct buildings?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've been constructing my base, but I put a corridor in the wrong place and need to deconstruct it. I can't find anything online telling me how to deconstruct buildings... is it possible, and how do I do it on the PC version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hold <kbd>z</kbd>, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, and the make sure that the piece you want to delete is highlighted in green. Hit <kbd>f</kbd> and it'll disappear.

Source: [https://steamcommunity.com](https://steamcommunity.com/app/275850/discussions/0/154642857137888062/)